# How to control different parent

Tags: parent

I have made the model and want to run on the curve path. With the model and the door i want to animate at some frame. To the door i have added empty and some part i parent. I added a sphere empty and parent complete model so that it follow along the path. The complete model get parent but the door empty when needed to rotate to open the door it does not work.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you parent the door object to the Empty Sphere, am I right? Don't do it, don't parent the door to the Empty Sphere, otherwise it won't be parented to the Empty Plain Axe anymore. Only parent the door to the Empty Plain Axe and the Empty Plain Axe (and the front of the object) to the Empty Sphere. When the Empty Sphere moves, the door will follow as it is child of its child. Is it not your problem?

To make it simple, let say you deparent everything to start from scratch, now what you need to do is : 1) parent the door to the Empty Plain Axe 2) parent the front and the Empty Plain Axe to the Empty Sphere.

Comment: Will getting confuse. Can you make it clear. Cross empty parented to door ok and sphere empty to rest of the model. You mean 2 empty and 2 part of the model.

Comment: Let say you deparent everything to start from scratch, now what you need to do is : 1) parent the door to the Empty Plain Axe 2) parent the front and the Empty Plain Axe to the Empty Sphere. That's all.

Comment: I have added the blend file to make the confusion clear.

Comment: Yes, it works if you do what I said

Comment: U mean 2 parent to half body but as mention above i need a single mesh to follow path on curve.

Comment: I don't think I understand, for example what is the problem with this file? [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5680" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5680/)

Comment: Ok i got it. Door+cross empty = parent, Front +sphere empty = parent. Then cross empty + sphere empty == parent.

Comment: Problem is how to follow path on the curve path after parenting to make 1 model

Comment: The Empty Sphere will be the object that will follow your curve, give it a Follow Path constraint and give it the curve as Target, sorry I must be missing the problem